# PNG image with transparency not displaying in xamarin forms (xaml)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have made a xamarin forms login screen and I want to put a logo in there, but it is not displaying. I have followed the instructions on the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#using-xaml

I am using xaml

I've tried following the link above but all that is displayed is a blank image, and if I use the following:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MaisonNickel.MainPage"

             Title="MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Image x:Name="cat" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrpcd.jpg

also there is no error displayed, I checked the filters, it's a vs bug not refreshing

Comment: Xamarin Forms Previewer has multiple bugs I would suggest you start checking in devices...

Comment: You don't seem to be adding a Source to the image, are you doing it in code behind? If no image source is set in the Image component, nothing will be displayed.

Comment: how do I add a the source?

Comment: @MateusW. how do I add it?

Comment: Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `Source` attribute to your `Image` so there is something to be displayed. You do it like this (in XAML):

```
<Image x:Name="cat" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="catImage.png"/>
```

Your "catImage.png" have to exist inside the resources of the platforms you want your app to work. So, for **Android**, add your image to *Resources/Drawable*, and for **iOS**, add it to *Resources* folder.

You can also add the image to your main project once and use it as `Embedded Resource`. If you want to do that, I recommend reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images).

Also, if you use a lot of images in your project and it starts losing performance, I recommend using some way of caching images, and for that, I recommend [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading). It handles caching, placeholder and fade animation to when the Image is loaded, check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you did follow **all the instructions**. It's pretty straightfoward. If you want to add the image via embedded resource (so in Xaml) here are the main points:

1) Import the image into your project and set it as ***embedded resource*** in the property window (assuming your image is called cat.png, placed in main folder and your assembly is MaisonNickel)

2) create a new Xaml markup extension in main folder

```
[ContentProperty (nameof(Source))]
public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
 public string Source { get; set; }

 public object ProvideValue (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
 {
   if (Source == null)
   {
     return null;
   }

   // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
   var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source, typeof(ImageResourceExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

   return imageSource;
 }
}
```

3) Then you must reference the assembly and replace the image source this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
   xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MaisonNickel;assembly=MaisonNickel"
   x:Class="MaisonNickel.MainPage">
   <ContentPage.Content>
      <Image x:Name="cat" Source="{local:ImageResource MaisonNickel.cat.png}" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

In your code, I don't see any referenced class for imageResource, neither the `Source` property.

Happy coding!